# build apk is not updated with latest changes

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-studio, apk

I am trying to build debug apk in my windows system to send for QA testing but it is not relecting any changes in latest apk.

steps i am following-

1. npx react-native link in root directory
2. npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
3. cd android
4. ./gradlew clean
5. ./gradlew assembleDebug

also i clean the build,clean the project, invalidated caches, deleted and created new index.android.bundle, deleted old build/apk before installing new one but nothing worked.

My Friend also tried using Mac still not resolved

please help if i am doing wrong or missed any step